# Any advice on 'breaking' an object out of its layout in Flex - for animation purposes?

Tags: apache-flex, layout, animation

If I have an object in a layout in Flex what is a good way to 'break it out' of that layout to be able to animate it.

For instance I have an image and a caption arranged at an angle. I want to make the image 'zoom out' slightly when the mouse rolls over it. Since its in a layout container is active if I were to resize it then obviously it would move around everything else.

I dont think I can achieve what I want by just setting `includeinlayout=false`.

Any experience with best practices on this?

My best idea I'm wondering about is making the image invisible and creating another image at the same location by using the screen coordinate conversion functions. This jsut semes clumsy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your object in a fixed size Canvas so that the layout upstream will remain the same. Then position the object manually within that container and then set its includeInLayout to false. At that point, you could do whatever you wanted with the interior object. Oh, also set clipContent to false. This should work whether you want it to grow or shrink.

If this is an itemrenderer or something that you've wrapped into a class, you could handle all of this in the class definition and make it transparent to consumers of the object. You'd also be able to write a mouseOver function that did what you wanted with the interior object that should zoom.